# Скачать и распаковать zip-архив

Tags: python, файлы, requests

Подскажите, как с помощью библиотеки requests считать данные по имеющемуся url в папку - без .zip?
Делаю:

```
r = requests.get('https:URL')
with open('?????', 'wb') as code:
    code.write(r.content)
```

Если я на месте ????? указываю файл, то он просто превращается папку с файлами(полученную из URL) непонятно во что.... Работает только с Name.zip, но потом нужно разорхивировать, что очень неудобно.

Comment: Например можно было заголовок такой написать: `Скачать и распаковать zip-архив`, подобное [уже делал](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/2414a59177cde3df7c9730e4e888011c8b6ed91e/requests_example/download_zip_and_extract_first_json_file_in_memory.py)

Answer (score 1):

```
import tempfile, os, zipfile

import requests

response = requests.get('https://URL')

file = tempfile.TemporaryFile()
file.write(response.content)
fzip = zipfile.ZipFile(file)
fzip.extractall('<куда распаковывать>')
file.close()
fzip.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы скачать и распаковать zip-архив в `output` папку в Питоне:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import io
import zipfile
import requests  # $ pip install requests

r = requests.get("http://www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/def/channel.zip")
with r, zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(r.content)) as archive:
    archive.extractall('output')
```

Если вы сразу хотите информацию из распакованных файлов в вашем коде использовать, то можно налету распаковывать и читать файлы:

```
with r, zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(r.content)) as archive:
    print({member.filename: archive.read(member)
           for member in archive.infolist()})
```

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйтесь [Документацией shutil.unpack_archive](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.unpack_archive)

```
shutil.unpack_archive(filename, extract_dir)
```